# Django-storages uploads to S3 causing Django to hang

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I prevent blocking when uploading to S3 using `django-storages`? My webserver currently gets about 100TPS and I have 17 workers (8 core cpu). After a bit of investigation I believe it's user content being uploaded that causes my webserver to hang.

1. Is there a way to use `django-storages` + S3 properly (that prevents the event loop from being blocked)?
2. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?
3. Or– do I simply need to continue scaling worker resources?

Comment: Any minimal sample code we can look at?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary unfortunately this is just a basic FileField being uploaded to with the basic Django Rest Framework FileField Serializer, most of the Django-storages stuff is invisible on the interface side, no?